# Agda Vec how to filter out elements

Tags: filter, agda

Hi I think I don't understand well how to use `Vec.filter` from `Data/Vec.agda`.

I know how to "filter in" (keep) elements in the vector

```
filterProof : v.filter (λ e → e ≟ 2) (2 v.∷ v.[]) ≡ (2 vb.∷ vb.[])
filterProof = refl
```

however I'm not sure how to "filter out" elements.

```
filterProof : v.filter (λ e → e ? 2) (2 v.∷ v.[]) ≡ vb.[]
filterProof = refl
```

I'm not sure what goes where `?` is.
I know the type needs to be `Relation.Nullary.Dec` but not sure how to express `e ≠ 2` using what's available in `Relation.Nullary.Dec`.

Also I would like to know why `Vec.filter` doesn't filter using a `Bool` instead of `Relation.Nullary.Dec` like `List.filter` does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn a decision procedure for a predicate into a decision procedure for its negation:

```
open import Relation.Nullary

dec-¬ : ∀ {a} {P : Set a} → Dec P → Dec (¬ P)
dec-¬ (yes p) = no λ prf → prf p
dec-¬ (no ¬p) = yes ¬p
```

which of course means you can negate decidable relations as well:

```
open import Relation.Binary

module _ {a} {A B : Set a} {ℓ} where
  neg : REL A B ℓ → REL A B ℓ
  neg R x y = ¬ (R x y)

  decidable-neg : ∀ {R : REL A B ℓ} → Decidable R → Decidable (neg R)
  decidable-neg dec x y = dec-¬ (dec x y)
```